# Нажатие на кнопку на странице с определенным URL

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы при переходе на определенный url нажималась кнопка, которая на странице находится, но почему то не получается.

```
 <script>
        let loginInp = document.querySelector('.login-form--hide');
        let emailInp = document.querySelector('.email-form--hide');
        let sendInp = document.querySelector('.send-form--hide');


        let loginLoc = window.localStorage.getItem('name');
        let emailLoc = window.localStorage.getItem('email');

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

            if (window.location.href === 'https://url.ru/success/') {
                loginInp.value = loginLoc;
                emailInp.value = emailLoc;

                sendInp.click();


            }
         });




    </script>
```

Хочу таким образом отправить форму, поля которой заполняю из local.Storage. Что не так? `click()` работает только с другим кликом или как? Как тогда поступить?

Comment: Вы уверены, что событие вообще срабатывает и что вы проваливаетесь в ваш if?

Comment: Условие срабатывает, так как данные из localStorage в инпуты добавляются

Comment: А `.send-form--hide` - кнопка?

Comment: да это кнопка и есть

Comment: Судя по имени класса, вы пытаетесь нажать на скрытую кнопку. А как она скрыта? Если, например, с помощью "display: none", то на странице этой кнопки фактически нет.

Comment: это я на будущее) она не скрыта по факту... то есть форма существует на странице и ее видно

Comment: вот думаю может надо подвязаться к событиям Dom, форма на worpdress плагином Contact form 7, то есть не нажимать кнопку а отправлять форму, но фиг знает как это сделать